# Which view should I select for previewing the real picture of Camera with Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I hope to preview the real picture of the camera of Android mobile phone in my App.

I google some resources, It seems that there are three view `SurfaceView`, `cameraview` and `SurfaceTexture` of `CameraX` alpha.

It seems that SurfaceView is classical, [cameraview](https://github.com/google/cameraview) is DEPRECATED, and SurfaceTexture of [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera) is alpha edition, you can see Image A

Which view should I select for previewing the real picture of Camera in Android Studio 3.4.1 with Kotlin? or you have the better ways?

**Image A**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean the 'real content' of the camera ? Is it as opposed to the 'fake content' of the camera ? What is it then ?

Comment: I open the camera of a mobile phone, the picture I will take is real content

Comment: When I move the camera, the picture in my mobile phone screen will change, so I think it's real picture

Comment: It also mean to preview picture of camera , the picture will change when I move  camera.

Comment: @HelloCW you can try fileprovider with uri on intent, i post my answer hope it helps you.

Comment: SurfaceView  is good for custom camera

Answer (score 0):

I think you could start with classical way and then when camerax is stable refactor and use it. Or you can use it even if is alpha, this is related with your project requirements. You can check implementation of camerax [here](https://github.com/android/camera).

Also there are sample projects in kotlin and java and also include video implementation with camerax in [gihtub](https://github.com/android/camera).

An alternative is to use a native sollution with FileProvider and camera Intent based on [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics). I think this is the best solution for now and implement camerax in future.

Answer (score -3):

TextureView

Please read the training document before asking question.
https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview